# Exibir produtos Subcategoria

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma loja virtual, mas não estou conseguindo exibir os produtos da subcategoria na página.

Os produtos da Categoria vão normal, mas os produtos da sub-categoria não.

Segue o código:

```
<?php 
    $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
    $categoria_sub = $_GET['categoria_sub'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produto
                         INNER JOIN categoria
                            ON produto.categoria = categoria.categoria_id
                         INNER JOIN categoria_sub
                            ON produto.categoria_sub = categoria_sub.sub_cat_id                                                     
                         WHERE produto.categoria = '".$categoria."' 
                           AND produto.categoria_sub = '".$categoria_sub."'
                        ORDER BY RAND()");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)== true) {
        while ($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
?>
```

Tabelas:

PRODUTO
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CATEGORIA
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SUBCATEGORIA
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloque a estrutura das suas tabelas e algum registro como exemplo, se possível utilize o SQLFiddle

Comment: post editado com a tabela

Comment: Leitura obrigatória: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/5878)

Comment: @BetinhoSilva onde ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis acabei de colocar

Comment: se uma sub-categoria, pertence a uma categoria, como um produto pode pertencer a uma categoria x, e a uma sub-categoria y onde y não é sub-categoria de x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se uma sub-categoria pertence a uma categoria, não é necessário ter no cadastro do produto uma fk para categoria e outra para sub-categoria, basta ter a sub-categoria. 
O Mesmo se aplica ao `WHERE` onde se você filtrar pela sub-categoria, automaticamente a categoria será filtrada pela condição `c.categoria_id = s.sub_cat_categoria`.

Tendo:

```
$categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
$categoria_sub = $_GET['categoria_sub'];
```

Segue o código:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN categoria_sub s on s.sub_cat_id = p.categoria_sub 
INNER JOIN categoria c on c.categoria_id = s.sub_cat_categoria
WHERE p.categoria_sub = '".$categoria_sub."'
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Se quiser filtrar apenas pela categoria:

Utilizando a chave que tem na tabela de produtos:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN categoria_sub s on s.sub_cat_id = p.categoria_sub 
INNER JOIN categoria c on c.categoria_id = s.sub_cat_categoria
WHERE p.categoria = '".$categoria."'
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Utilizando a chave relacionada na sub-categoria:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN categoria_sub s on s.sub_cat_id = p.categoria_sub 
INNER JOIN categoria c on c.categoria_id = s.sub_cat_categoria
WHERE c.categoria_id = '".$categoria."'
ORDER BY RAND()
```

**UPDATE**

Utilizando a chave relacionada na sub-categoria (sem filtrar), se nada for passado no GET categoria:

```
$where_categoria = '';

if($categoria != '') {
    $where_categoria = "WHERE c.categoria_id = '".$categoria."'";
}

SELECT 
* 
FROM produto p
INNER JOIN categoria_sub s on s.sub_cat_id = p.categoria_sub 
INNER JOIN categoria c on c.categoria_id = s.sub_cat_categoria
".$where_categoria."
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Boa... e pra eu pegar apenas a categoria? $categoria = $_GET['categoria']; Porque qdo clicar no link com o nome da categoria irá aparecer todos produtos da categoria...

Comment: editado, veja se te atende

Comment: como faço para pegar isso na página q faço a lista.... todos os resultados tem q vir para a página produto_listar.php se eu coloco uma das opções ou vem somente a categoria ou somente a sub

Comment: Nunca tinha pensado em randomizar a saída de uma query, seu `ORDER BY RAND()` me abriu horizontes

Comment: @BetinhoSilva Você pode simplesmente "ignorar" a linha caso não for informado sub_categoria ou categoria. Vou editar a resposta do amigo para você.

Comment: @Cava eu usei if... deu certo

Comment: @BetinhoSilva Eu editei, porém precisava que alguém aprovasse a minha edição ali. Por isso você não recebeu minha edição aí.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado também gostei desse `ORDER BY RAND()` mas no caso específico, não utilizaria rsrs. Ordenar produtos, certamente seria por ordem alfabética, ou por um rank de quantidades vendidas, algo assim